# HTTP POST Request with Json body giving error code 400

Tags: java, json, http, post

I'm trying to send a `Json` format in body of `POST` request in `java`.

I tried a lot of codes from the internet and StackOverflow, but nothing is working.

I keep getting `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/message`.

After trying a lot on Postman i noticed it only accepts Json format body, i tried using json libraries like Gson, yet still nothing worked.

Any ideas on how to fix my code? Again I did try to copy a lot of codes from the internet so please don't send me a similar title stackoverflow thread and call the question repetitive.

Thank you in advance.

```
public class PostRequest {

    FileWriter myWriter;
    URL url;
    public void sendPost(String Url) throws IOException {
        
        String name = "{\"messageName\": \"URLFound\", \"businessKey\": \"3\"}";
        
        try {
            myWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\camunda test save\\Post.txt");
            url = new URL ("http://localhost:8080/engine-rest" + Url);
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setDoOutput(true);
            http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            
            OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream();
            byte[] input = name.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
            
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((in.ready())) {
                response.append(in.readLine());
            }
            in.close();
            
            //Writing result on .txt
            myWriter.append(response.toString() + "\n" +url);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            myWriter.append(e.toString());
        }
        myWriter.close();
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the server code as well?

Comment: I don't have access to the server code, I'm sending the request to Camunda webapp

Answer (score 1):

How about using this client project?
https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-rest-client-spring-boot/

For example:
https://github.com/camunda-community-hub/camunda-rest-client-spring-boot/blob/dce6bd777e3350dd30286311c5351aa9460a34f4/examples/example/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/extension/rest/example/standalone/client/ProcessClient.java#L98

Answer (score 0):

Java cant create an object from your json. Check if all fields are sent in the request body of the java class that is expected on the backend side.